# How to display images from external RSS feeds in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, rss, thumbnails

Is there any way to show an image from RSS feeds in my WordPress page? Currently the default WordPress RSS feeds will only show the text of feeds from other sites. How can I make my site show a thumbnail image of RSS feeds of the other sites?

I'm using WordPress 3.01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin to display images from RSS feeds:-

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/01/27/custom-fields-for-feeds-wordpress-plugin

Comment: no. can u look at blog.justenglish.com..see the feeds at the sidebar..i want that rss feeds shwo the post image also